# how to modify AndroidMainfest.xml without apktool?

Tags: android

I want to modify a lot of apk files, and need to write 
 
in Mainfest.xml. If use apktool, it is too slow, is there a way to modify AndroidManifest without apktool

Answer (score -2):

> You plenty of Online Decompilers also.. but i you needs are to use a
>   pc software check this two options:

*Best alternative is the* [Apk Studio](https://github.com/vaibhavpandeyvpz/apkstudio)

*Or the* [Easy Tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/tool-apk-easy-tool-v1-02-windows-gui-t3333960)

Comment: A comment would have worked perfectly as you have enough reputation to post comments....but instead you post a link-only-answer...Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: I didnt knew.. im new here too

Comment: this tow tools is depend on apktool ,  100 apks unzip  spent long time